# UICollectionView scrollRectToVisible and scrollToItem break user scroll

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am using this code to reveal a specific item in a collection view.

```
var pages: [PDFPage]?

var currentPage: PDFPage?

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    // Scroll to currently opened page
    if let current = currentPage, let idx = pages?.firstIndex(of: current) {
        collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: idx, section: 0), at: .centeredVertically, animated: false)
    }
}
```

It is working as expected but it completely locks user scrolling in order, I guess, to always keep the item in the requested position. 
The same happens when using scrollRectToVisible.
Instead I'd like it to only move to the item, and then let the user scroll wherever he wants. Which is the behaviour I'm getting with UITableViewController's scrollToRow.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you please add more context? When do you call the method? It would be great if you provide a GIF or images that illustrate your problem

Comment: @fewlinesofcode thanks! I've updated the description with the code and a video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out calling the scroll in viewDidLayoutSubviews was the issue, because it was continuously repeated and preventing any further scroll. I solved the issue like this:

```
var currentPage: PDFPage?

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    // Scroll to currently opened outline
    if let current = currentPage, let idx = pages?.firstIndex(of: current) {
        collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: idx, section: 0),
                                     at: .top,
                                     animated: false)

        // In order to only run the scroll once, without locking the view
        currentPage = nil
    }
}
```